# Will plist file be overwritten when app update is released

Tags: ios, app-store, plist, updating

I have an app that is currently on apples App Store. It stores users data in a number of plist files that are saved on the iPad within the apps documents.

I want to release an update of my app but am unsure wether doing so will re-write the plist files and lose any data that the user has input into that app.

Basically i need to know:

A) Wether this happens or if it uses the plist files that are already stored in the apps documents.

B) If it does rewrite it is there any way of getting round this so the users do not lose all there data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When performing an update all that will be updated is the bundle contents. The documents folder will not be touched in any way.

Comment: Thank you, that is good news. Your answer is much appreciated.